# Validar conteúdo de TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho os campos `TextBox`, por exemplo:

- `txtValorCompra` teria que ser digitado pelo usuário `98,90` e não pode ser letras
- `txtNumero` entrada com números inteiros
- `nome` somente letras.

Teria como fazer isso no formulário?

Comment: Você pode usar um outro controle que permite usar uma máscara ([MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)). Ou usar o sistema de [eventos do controle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx) para validar manualmente o que foi entrado durante a digitação ou ao final dela.

Comment: Alguma coisa para você ler: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220519/Numbers-or-Characters-only-Textbox-Validation-in-C, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399323/validating-whether-a-textbox-contains-only-numbers,

Answer (score 3):

pessoal fiz uma coisa que deu certo vou postar aqui para ajudar outros usuarios

```
        //não permitir augumas coisas 
        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || //Letras

            char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) || //Símbolos

            char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar)) //Espaço

            e.Handled = true; //Não permitir

        //só permitir digitar uma vez a virgula
        if (e.KeyChar == ','
            && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Em meu projeto, tive a necessidade de desenvolver vários controles para atender necessidades específicas e uma delas era justamente a questão acima. Desenvolvi um UserControl que aceitava apenas números. O componente seguiu a referência presente no link abaixo:
http://www.vcskicks.com/numbers_only_textbox.php

Answer (score 1):

Precisei fazer isso em um projeto recente.

O que eu fiz foi utilizar o evento `Leave` do `TextBox` para validar os dados usando REGEX.

```
public const string EXPRESSAO = @"^\d+(\,\d{1,2})?$"; //Expressão para validar decimais

private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;

    var valido = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text.Trim(), EXPRESSAO);

    if (!valido)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Valor inválido!");
        tb.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar uma [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para o que pretende. A propriedade [`Mask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) permite-lhe definir quais são os *inputs* aceites.

No seu caso a `Mask` ficaria:

- txtValorCompra (98,90) => 00,00 (Obrigatório introduzir 4 números, a `MaskedTextBox` coloca automaticamente o separador decimal);
- txtNumero => 0000 (Obrigatório colocar 4 números);
- nome somente letras => LLLL (Obrigatório colocar 4 caracteres);

Existem mais [combinações](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que pode utilizar.

Finalmente no seu codigo, para validar e usar o texto introduzido:

```
aminhamaskedTextBox.ValidateText();
```

Se necessitar de apresentar uma mensagem ao utilizador quando o *input* introduzido e invalido, pode utilizar o evento `aminhamaskedTextBox_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)`.

Answer (score -3):

```cs
void validar_TextBox() {
  foreach (Control verifica in this.TabControl.Controls) {
    if (verifica.GetType().Equals(typeof(TextBox)) ||                    
    verifica.GetType().Equals(typeof(MaskedTextBox)) ||
    verifica.GetType().Equals(typeof(ComboBox))) {
      if (verifica.Text == string.Empty) {
        verifica.BackColor = Color.cyan;
      }
    }
  }
```